# ViewModel is null on second AJAX Post

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have PartialView which display pricing information and allow users to enter promocode. when clicking the button on _ListItem.cshtml on the first time, the HttpPost method manage to grab the OrderDetailsViewModel.Details and process in the controller. on the second click of the button, it couldn't capture the data in the Model.

[image: First Post]

[image: Second Post]

Here are my codes.

**NewPurchaseViewModel**

```
public class NewPurchaseViewModel{
    public NewPurchaseViewModel()
    {
        Details = new OrderDetailsViewModel();
        Shipping = new Address();
        Billing = new Address();
    }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   ...
   public OrderDetailsViewModel Details { get; set; }
}
```

**OrderDetailsViewModel**

```
public class OrderDetailsViewModel{
  public OrderDetailsViewModel()
  {
        Items = new List<ItemsOrderViewModel>();
        Shipping = 0.00M;
  }
  public string Promocode { get; set; }
  public string SubTotal{ get; set; }
  public string Total{ get; set; }
  public string Discount{ get; set; }
  public string Shipping{ get; set; }
  public List<ItemsOrderViewModel> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**Info.cshtml**

```
@model ~.ViewModels.NewPurchaseViewModel
...
@Html.Partial("~/Views/CheckOut/_ListItem.cshtml", Model.Details, new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Details"} })
```

**_ListItem.cshtml**

```
@model Nutric.hive.eStore.ViewModels.OrderDetailsViewModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Verify", "PromoCode", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "divPromoCode",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}))
{
    <table>
    ...
    <tbody>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Model.Items[i].ProductPackage.Name</td>
            <td class="qty">@Model.Items[i].Quantity</td>
            <td class="price">@Model.Items[i].ItemTotal</td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Items[i].ProductPackage.Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Items[i].ProductPackage.Name)
            @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Items[i].ProductPackage.Description)
            @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Items[i].ProductPackage.ImageURL)
            @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Items[i].ProductPackage.Status)
            @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Items[i].ProductPackage.RetailPrice)
            @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Items[i].ProductPackage.TaxCode)
            @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Items[i].ProductPackage.PackageCode)
            @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Items[i].Quantity)
            @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Items[i].ItemTotal)
        </tr>
    }
    ...
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Promocode, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 15, placeholder = "Type Voucher Code Here...", type = "text" })
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Apply !">
                    </span>
                </div>
             </div>
         </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Discount)
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Shipping)
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Subtotal)
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Total)
}

@section Script{

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
}
```

**PromoCodeController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Verify(NewPurchaseViewModel postModel)
{
    OrderDetailsViewModel odvm = postModel.Details;
    //some logic here to check the promo code.
    return PartialView("~/Views/CheckOut/_ListItem.cshtml",odvm );
}
```

Comment: Because when you post the first form thse form controls are correctly named with the `Details` prefix. When you return the view and update the DOM, the name attributes no longer have the prefix, therefore do no match you model. Why in the world are you degrading performance by generating all those hidden inputs? Use a view model containing only the properties you need - which appears to be just `Promocode`

Comment: Hi, @StephenMuecke thanks for the prompt reply. Is there anyway that i can work around on this issue ? Thanks for the tips, will need promocode and product package as i will need to compare promotional items which match only with the promo code. and will also need to list the price & quantity for these items. will remove those unnecessary codes as suggested.

Comment: Your form should contain and post back the `Promocode` value since that is  the only thing that is editable. Its not clear from your code what that property is for, but at the moment your posting back a whole lot a data (which can easily be manipulated by a malicious user), and then sending it all back again unchanged which makes no sense.